# spoofed mac address changes when trying to connect to network

Tags: networking

So I need to spoof my mac address to access a network. I can spoof it fine with the ifconfig commands, but when I try to connect to the network it gets reset back to the default mac address. Changing the mac address in the persistent.rules file does not fix it either, it still gets reset to the default. How do I do this so it does not change back once I try to connect? As well if I try to put in the new mac address in the cloned mac address field under edit connections, it still uses the default mac. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.1

Comment: Does your networking hardware support MAC address spoofing?

Comment: Its a known problem with the current builds. I found a work around on the Ubuntu forums. You need to stop the network manager, change the mac, then turn the manager back on

Comment: @skinnydude Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: @Fabby Sorry, I haven't looked here in a while! I just posted the answer if you still needed it.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to the solution is:

```
sudo service network-manager stop

sudo ifconfig wlan0 down

sudo macchanger -m XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX wlan0

sudo ifconfig wlan0 up

sudo service network-manager start
```

The `macchanger` line can be replaced with whatever `macchanger` command you need. or with `sudo ifconfig wlan0 hw ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`

Answer (score 0):

I came across with this problem a few days ago after updating "Kali”.

I use Kali Linux 2016.2 (64 bit), by the way. Before updating/upgrading the system through its repositories, mac changer was working like a charm.

However, soon after the update, I tried to spoof my MAC address in order to bypass some MAC filtering I've set up in my own network, and every time I attempted to do it (and there were several tries), my MAC address was automatically reverted to, or its permanent burnt-in address, or a random one.

At first, I was not sure about what could be possibly causing it, but after doing some tests, using different devices, tools and setups, I found out that the issue was being originated by Network Manager, which I realized later being not an issue exactly, but just a different default configuration of the service than the one we were used to.

The latest versions of Network Manager, 1.4.2, in this particular case, implement several configuration options for MAC spoofing/cloning, and when put in use, these options tend to override any configurations set by tools like mac changer and macchito, making them practically useless.

It turns out that, in its newer versions (above 1.2, but more notably the versions above 1.4, which dispenses wpa_supplicant support for this purpose), NetworkManager default configurations are set to randomize your MAC address or revert it to the permanent one at the moment your interface scans the networks around you or attempt to connect into one of them. This new feature is very interesting for purposes of anonymity; for MAC spoofing, however, it can complicate the authentication process.

Disabling this feature is very simple, you'll just need to change some NetworkManager's configurations.

You can do this either by editing `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` file or adding an additional `.conf` file to `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d` directory (the .conf file can have any name).

Though I highly recommend the second option, given that when updated, Network Manager usually replaces its main .conf file, and if you choose the first option, your saved options may be overwritten when the service gets these updates from time to time.

Whatever option you choose, in the text editor, add the following lines:
Code:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[connection]
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
```

Then save the file, and inside the terminal, restart NetworkManager by typing in:
Code:

```
service network-manager restart

OR

systemctl restart NetworkManger
```

And it's done, the problem now should have been resolved.