# What reason would cause MAC address spoofing not to work?

Tags: networking, mac

I was unable to find the solution to this here, or on Google.

I have followed the standard instructions to spoof your MAC address, readily available online in places such as:

1. https://www.maketecheasier.com/change-mac-address-windows-ubuntu/
2. [How do I change / spoof my MAC address and easily switch between multiple ones?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81648/how-do-i-change-spoof-my-mac-address-and-easily-switch-between-multiple-ones)
3. [How to change the MAC address of pc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390147/how-to-change-the-mac-address-of-pc)

It never works. It *used* to work, actually. Then it just stopped working successfully. What happens: I can change it, using those instructions, but I can't connect to any networks. Not *any* network at all. Something weird is going on in my operating system.

Edit: StackX is asking that I must edit this question because it is answered on askubuntu already. In fact, the link to the answer is what I already noted as Source 2. Simply put, I already followed those instructions and they did not work. As I said already, they used to work, but something changed on my OS and I am looking for help in tracking that down.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change / spoof my MAC address and easily switch between multiple ones?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/81648/how-do-i-change-spoof-my-mac-address-and-easily-switch-between-multiple-ones) Have you followed the suggestions here? Which ones? Please described what happened.

Comment: Yes I did follow those. I linked to that in the OP: "It used to work, actually. Then it just stopped working successfully. What happens: I can change it, using those instructions, but I can't connect to any networks. Not any network at all."

Comment: Some ISPs rely on the Mac address for connection authentication. If MAC address is not recognized, dns or other services are unavailable. Also, how is this not a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/838117/why-does-mac-address-cloning-not-allow-me-to-connect-to-any-wifi-networks

Comment: Thank you @BenjaminBrink. It does not work 20+ WiFi networks I've tried it on.  It is a duplicate, but it was never answered, and I'm desperate for a solution.

Comment: Have you tried this solution? http://askubuntu.com/questions/586269/spoofed-mac-address-changes-when-trying-to-connect-to-network

Comment: Could be a problem trying to connect with an invalid mac address.  Not every mac address is valid. You should use `macchanger -r` option instead. Also, is your device in managed or monitor mode?